# Unresolved import: ALModule

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, nao-robot

I have a problem unresolved import :ALModule (eclipse with python). This is my error

ALModule Found at: facecount.FaceCounterModule

from naoqi import ALModule

Can you help me, please!

Comment: Your error message is not well reported. You should say exactly what operation you did to produce the error and copy/paste the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [check again the proper installation procedure](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/sdks/python-sdk/python-sdk-installation-guide#-installing-the-sdk-).
Make sure your `PYTHONPATH` is well set to where you unzipped the NAOqi Python SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. Yes, I need to change in my PYTHONPATH with C:\Users\......\python27\Lib\site_packages\pynaoqi\lib  . Now I am ok for that error.  Where pynaoqi is renamed of unzipped the NAOqi Python SDK.